# arduino Serial.readStringUntil('\r') - multiple lines input

Tags: string, arduino, esp8266

I'm quite new to Arduino programming and to coding itself.
I'm trying to read some strings from serial (to send them later by ESP8266) and my simple sketch works with no problems with a lot of them.

```
while(Serial.available()){
String termdata = Serial.readStringUntil('\r');
```

There's a case when my `termdata` string (actually a GSM AT command) is split onto two lines.

e.g.

```
AT+CMGW=+39XXXXXXXXXX,
1234567890abcdef
```

and that `\r` terminator (I guess) gives me just the first line of my stream, while I actually should need to get the second one (`1234567890abcdef`).

Since I need to read other strings too that are using `\r` terminator, how could I get data from that second line without loosing other strings?

Comment: read string to `\0` in temp variable and then you can parse by `\n`

Comment: thanks a lot, I was able to retrieve the string reading to \0, then I correctly parsed by \r tokenizing it using strtok